# Syntax while trying to include The multi-part identifier [°C] in command text

Tags: excel, ado.net, jet

I am trying to copy data directly from a Microsoft Excel file into the database using Asp.net. The problem is that the spreadsheet has a column named `Product[°C]`, which, when I include in the query, fails to parse as valid SQL.

I'm using the following code from an example on how to [connect to and query an Excel file via OleDb and Ado.net](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Import-data-from-Excel-to-GridView-in-ASPNet.aspx).

```cs
var conStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0},HDR={1}";
conStr = String.Format(conStr, FilePath, isHDR);
OleDbConnection connExcel = new OleDbConnection(conStr);
OleDbCommand cmdExcel = new OleDbCommand();
connExcel.Open();
var SheetName = "Sheet1$";

// ...
cmdExcel.CommandText = "SELECT [Date/time] as [Date/time], [Product[°C]]] as [Product] From [" + SheetName + "] ";
```

Here the problem bit is `[Product[°C]]]`. The debugger gives an error saying:

> Additional information: Syntax error in query expression '[Product[°C]]]'.

Where as if I want to do query a table with [Product[°C]]] in SQL I can do it via using:

```sql
Select id, [Product[°C]]] from TableName
```

This query parses fine in SQL but not when I query Excel. Why not?

Comment: What do you mean, "doesn't work in ASP.NET"? That's ridiculous. Please show the code you're using.

Comment: I am getting the following error  
Additional information: Syntax error in query expression '[Product[°C]]]'.

Comment: Show the code you are using.

Comment: `+ SheetName +` may be exploited with Sql Injection attack

Comment: Are you querying the excel spreadsheet directly with the JET driver, or did you import this into SQL server? The reason is that the SQL parser for each engine is different.

Comment: I have updated the question with more code if this helps thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "SQL"? SQL Server? Oracle?

Comment: @JohnSaunders Sorry I didn't follow the question.

Comment: What are you querying? A database? Excel spreadsheet?

Comment: Through the code I am trying to copy the data in the spreadsheet into the database. The connection and everything worked perfectly fine but after I included column names instead of * I have started getting errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've finally deducted that you are using the Excel Jet driver to connect directly to the Excel spreadsheet. This driver uses a SQL engine which has some... unique features.

One feature is to convert square brackets in a column name to parentheses. What you want is likely this:

```sql
 cmdExcel.CommandText = "select [Date/Time], [Product(°C)] from [Sheet1$]";
```

Note the use of '(' in place of '['.

Comment: I tried this and I am getting following error
Error 1 Unrecognized escape sequence
Error 2 Unrecognized escape sequence

Comment: Did you add the "Escape" clause?

Comment: Yes this is what I wrote '[Product\[°C\]]'

Comment: No, you need to also add "ESCAPE '\'" at the end.

Comment: Thanks
I just copied and pasted the code. I am still getting the error unrecognised escape sequence

Comment: And I wrote [Product[°C]]] with in an extra bracket as it multi-part-identifier for SQL and its works fine if I write the command in SQL

Comment: Ok, I followed the link which you slapped on the end of your question. Please, next time, just start by explaining exactly what you are doing.

Comment: Thank you for your help and your time. I changed the code to  Select * and then mapping the columns. Your solution is acceptable and correct as well. Thank you